# About using cron in Linux to schedule my python program

Tags: python, linux, cron

I want to use cron to hourly run a python program in Linux(ubuntu). I wrote a script called script.sh

```
cd Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/
scrapy crawl AmtCrawler --set FEED_URI=data.json --set FEED_FORMAT=json
```

Then I used

```
crontab -e
```

and add a line like this

```
*/30 * * * * sh Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/script.sh 2>&1 >> /Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/output.log
```

After this, I run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
```

in terminal. It said

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the
>   service(8) utility, e.g. service cron start Since the script you are
>   attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may
>   also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start cron

So I run this

```
service cron start
```

Then there was an error:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.196" (uid=1000 pid=12574 comm="start cron ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Now I'm stuck with this problem asking for some help.

Comment: cron should be started, no need to start it. I think the error is because only root can manage cron, try using `sudo`

Comment: +RC Thanks. I used sudo and it worked. However, I didnt get the any result from the program. The output log file is that, but it's empty.

Comment: If `script.sh` has execute permission (`chmod +x script.sh`), then the `sh` should be unnecessary (but harmless).

Answer (score 2):

`cron(8)` is always running. You do not need to start or restart it when you make changes to your `crontab(5)` file using `crontab -e`:

```
   Additionally, cron checks each minute to see if its spool
   directory's modtime (or the modtime on /etc/crontab) has
   changed, and if it has, cron will then examine the modtime on
   all crontabs and reload those which have changed.  Thus cron
   need not be restarted whenever a crontab file is modified.
   Note that the crontab(1) command updates the modtime of the
   spool directory whenever it changes a crontab.
```

(The last sentence is the reason why it is always recommended to use the `crontab(1)` program when modifying your own `crontab(5)` file.)

Comment: The problem is that I can't get result from the scheduled python program, while there was a output log file, but nothing in it.

Comment: Cool, that's a result. Is `Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/script.sh` in the `PATH` of your `crontab(5)` file? If not, either give the full path to the executable in the `crontab(5)`, or add the path to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: yes, I have changed to the full path, but still not working.

Comment: Are there any errors in `/var/log/*` that look related?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is the whole problem, but your output redirections are reversed.  Rather than:

```
command 2>&1 >> /path/to/output.log
```

(which redirects stderr to stdout and then redirects stdout, *but not stderr* to `output.log`), you need:

```
command >> /path/to/output.log 2>&1
```

As others have said, the `service cron start` command shouldn't be necessary; `crond` should already be running (as you've already confirmed by getting an empty log file).

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo service cron start`.

Comment: Now the cron can start. However, I didn't get any result from the scheduled python program. (I have tested the python program.) The output log file is there but nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
*/30 * * * * sh Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/script.sh 2>&1 >> /Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/output.log
```

You need the full path for your dropbox directory. It is not under /.

Try this (assuming the Dropbox directory is `$HOME/Dropbox`):

```
*/30 * * * * sh $HOME/Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/script.sh >> $HOME/Dropbox/NetworkProject/AMT_Crawler/output.log 2>&1
```

Note that this changes *both* references to the `Dropbox` directory.  It also fixes the ordering of the redirection operators; see my (Keith Thompson's) answer.